# Кэшировать строку каждого пользователя

Tags: php, кэширование, dle

Скажите как правильно делать кэширование dle?

```
if(empty($errors) === true){
    $db->query("UPDATE ".USERPREFIX."_users SET user_text='{$user_text' WHERE user_id='{$member_id['user_id']}'");
}
```

Допустим пользователь ввел данные и эти данные записываются `MySQL`, как мне кэшировать строку каждого пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

можно класть во временный файл

```
file_put_contents("cache_".$member_id['user_id'].".txt",$user_text); // записать в файловый кеш
$user_text = file_get_contents("cache_".$member_id['user_id'].".txt"); //прочитать из файлового кеша
```